# Soap request using apache camel blueprint on apache karaf fails

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm trying to send a soap request with camel blueprint and by now I got this blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

<bean id="serviceBean" class="osgiBlueprintSoap.Service"/>

<cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint" 
    address="{http://some.url/services/}SomeService"
    wsdlUrl="{http://some.url/services/}SomeService?wsdl"
    serviceName="{http://some.url/services/}SomeService"
    portName="{http://some.url/services/}SomeServiceSoapPort">
    <properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="MESSAGE"/>
    </properties>
</cxfEndpoint>  

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route id="timerToLog">
    <from uri="timer:foo?period=5000"/>
    <to uri="cxf:serviceBean:serviceEndpoint"/>
    <to uri="file:C:/output?fileName=db.txt"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

The class Service is just an empty class right now.

After deploying it on karaf I get this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'cxfEndpoint'. One of '{"http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0":service, "http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0":reference-list, "http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0":bean, "http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0":reference, WC[##other:"http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"]}" is expected.
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with that xml and what I can do to be able to send this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML parser runs into error since it won't know what *cxfEndpoint* is. You must have correct XML namespace defined for your route to work like this:

```
xmlns:camelcxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
```

and then make reference to cxfEndpoint like this "camelcxf:cxfEndpoint".

You can see more complete Blueprint CXF example similar to your question in Camel source [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-cxf-blueprint/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/camel-context.xml).